# Как заменить текст в строке, если там есть только один символ?

Tags: notepad++

Как заменить текст в строке, если там есть только один символ?
Например, есть в 1 строке символ "-", во 2 - "-+-", и.т.д.
Как заменить значение в 1 строке "-" (оно одно в строке), но во второй минус не убирать.

Comment: Если одно, то можно и вручную. Если таких строк для замены много, то выбрать в окне замены опцию "спецсимволы" или регулярные выражение и нужным образом подправить заменяемый текст.

Comment: @Эникейщик , более 3 тыс. строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать замену по регулярному выражению и в заменяемом указать маркеры начала и конца строки: `^-$`.